# How can I use sqlmap to get only a certain number of records in SQL Server using a LIMIT and OFFSET?

Tags: sqlmap

I'm trying to dump using sqlmap, I have 3 columns:
name, lastname, userid with 9000 entries in each.

When I just `--dump` the table, it will start from 1 to 9000.

I don't want all the 9000, how can I tell it to start from 5000 and stop at 9000?

I tried the `--start=` and `--stop=` but it didn't help.

Comment: You can use `--sql-query` to specify an ordinary SQL statement.

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: @sivi109 `--sql-query="SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 4000 OFFSET 5000"`?

Answer (score 2):

## --sql-query

Like Arminius said, you can use `--sql-query` to specify an ordinary SQL statement. Provided you know the table/database name, you could use something like this:

```
--sql-query="use db; SELECT * FROM table OFFSET 5000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4000 ROWS ONLY;"
```

That would only work on SQL Server 2012 and above. For earlier versions, you'll need something like [ROW_NUMBER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server).