# Dump specific rows from database using sqlmap

Tags: sqlmap

I'm trying to dump using sqlmap, I have 3 columns: userid, email, password with 2900000 entries in each.

When I just `--dump` the table, it will start from 1 to 2900000.

I don't want all the 2900000, how can I tell it to start from like 500000 and stop at 600000?

I tried the `--start=` and `--stop=` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `--where` to specify a constraint (for example you could do `--where "ID=1000"` to return only the record with an ID of 1000) or you can use the standard `--start`/`--stop` parameters.

As per [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167946/how-can-i-use-sqlmap-to-get-only-a-certain-number-of-records-in-sql-server-using) you could also specify --sql-query="" to specify the select statement yourself for full control over the record set returned.

Comment: Can I use like operator inside where clause e.g. `--where "Id like '*AHWR43*'" ` . I need alternative to this types of command at least to dump only partially corrupt ids.